# getting attribute from parent selector is CSS using content:attr();

Tags: html, css

Hey I am trying to place the 'title' attribute of a <section> tag inside a <h3> tag located just below and inside the <section> tag.The following works

```
   <section title="General Information">
       <h3>General Information</h3>
       ....
   </section>
```

what I would like to do is not repeat 'General Information' inside the <h3> tag but use CSS content along with attr() to get the info inside of the tittle attribute in the <section> tag and place it inside the <h3> tags.

```
   <section title="General Information">
       <h3></h3>
       ....
   </section>

   section h3:after 
   {
       content:attr(title);
   }
```

This as expected looks for the 'title' attribute inside of the <h3> tag instead of the <section> tag. Is there any way I can achieve what I am trying to accomplish? Is what I am trying to accomplish the right way of doing things? I know I could skip the <h3> tags altogether and format the <section> tag to display whatever text is in 'title' attribute the same way that the <h3> tag would.

Comment: You would not want to generate your `h3` text that way anyway, because it would leave the `h3` blank for search engines. If anything, to reduce duplication, you should get rid of the `title` on the `section` and use the `h3` only as the "title".

Comment: I add similar problem, and I found this post useful. I hope it will help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034739/using-attribute-value-of-a-parent-in-a-child-using-css3-attr-function

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `attr()` function can only obtain an attribute from the element that's generating the content. You won't be able to get the `section` element's `title` because it's not the element that's generating the content.

As ScottS mentions, you should really avoid having an empty heading element, as there wouldn't be a point in having it there at all then. Your best bet is to either leave out the `title` attribute (is it really needed?), or leave the content duplicated.