# using attribute value of a parent in a child using CSS3 attr function

Tags: css

I want to set a `data-index` value of a parent element on one of its (nested) children. Desired result: string "index" should appear around the `h2.heading`.

Markup:

```
<div class="foo" data-index="index">
    <div>
        <h2 class="heading"><span>title</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (the first `data-index` rule works - but not in the right place):

```
div.foo[data-index] .heading span {
    display: none;
}

div.foo[data-index]::after { 
    content: attr(data-index);
    color: green;
}

div.foo[data-index] .heading::after { 
    content: attr(data-index);
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyxdoz

Comment: The problem is that I don't think you can pull the `attr(data-index)` from a parent of an element in CSS3. You'd have to have the `data-index` property in the `div.foo > div` element that is wrapping the header in order to put an `::after` pseudo on it.

Comment: @forrestmid I'm suspecting that; is there any reading I could do on this?

Comment: Yeah, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) has a definition on it. Specifically, "The attr() CSS function is used to retrieve the value of an attribute of the **selected element** and use it in the style sheet." I did a bit of research and wasn't able to find anything saying that it could be done with a child element.

Comment: just added a workaround version that sets a CSS variable directly on the html element.

Answer (score 22):

**update**

A workaround could be to set a CSS variable directly on the html element and use that.

```css
div.foo[data-index] .heading span {
    display: none;
}

div.foo[data-index] .heading::after { 
    content: var(--index);
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" style="--index:'test';" data-index>
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading"><span>title</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**original**

It can't be done currently (*as mentioned the `attr` only works on the current element*).

In the future, when [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) can be used to properties besides the `content`, combined with css variables you could do it like this

```css
div.foo[data-index] .heading span {
  display: none;
}
div.foo[data-index] {
  --data: attr(data-index);
  --index: var(--data);
}
div.foo[data-index] .heading::after {
  content: var(--index);
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" data-index="index">
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading"><span>title</span></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would the variables approach work in latest Chrome (only browser I need to support internally)? It's listed as supported at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

Comment: @montrealist yes it will work with latest Chrome. Here is the updated Pen: http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/KaedNx

Comment: Very elegant hack, if I can say so.

Comment: Coming from the future where you can use attr()  in css variables. The second snippet still doesn't work because the css-variable actually holds the attr() function which will thus get computed on the current target (.heading).

Comment: @Kaiido good catch. Updated to use `var` to evaluate it on the spot.

Answer (score -1):

One more alternative:

If the value is inheritable, and it is not set on the child directly. Then you could also assign it to parent with `attr()` and make do the inheritance do its thing.

Answer (score -3):

You could use this css.

```
div.foo[data-index]::after, div.foo[data-index]::before { 
    content: attr(data-index);
    color: green;
}

div.foo[data-index] .heading::after { 
    content: attr(data-index);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Note the use of the `:before` pseudo element.

I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Nope - that just puts the value at `data-index` before the `div.foo` - I need it inside the heading.

Comment: As you will most likely have to add the data-index attribute to the h2 element. dont see a way around it.