# attr binding is not working while using ::ng-deep on mat-toggle in angular

Tags: angular, sass, ng-deep

I want to change the 'content' property of a CSS class which is getting applied on Slide-Toggle of angular.

this is my SCSS -

```
:host .red {
  .mat-toggle {
    ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-bar{
      &::after{
        content: attr(data-active);;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I pass attrs  -

```
<div class="red"
attr.data-active="activeData">
    <mat-toggle></mat-toggle>
</div>
```

If I hard-code the value in CSS then it's working properly, but unable to bind the string dynamically.

Please help.

Comment: Can you make example on StackBlitz?

Comment: `::ng-deep` is deprecated, try styling in global `scss` file

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azgink?file=src/app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.css this is stackblitz link. you can see hard-coded 'foo', but I am not able to see the value of activeLabel on other slider.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `attr()` will not pierce down to the child element to set a value... it only works on `selected element`.

Reference to `MDN` that specifies `selected element` in the description.

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr())
>
> The attr() CSS function is used to retrieve the value of an attribute of the `selected element` and use it in the stylesheet. It can also be used on pseudo-elements, in which case the value of the attribute on the pseudo-element's originating element is returned.

With this in mind, you would need to set the attribute value into a CSS variable for later use.

---

Using the following approach from this SO answer may be a viable workaround.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035304/6581173

Add `label-attr` to be used in `CSS` via attribute selector, then set `custom property/CSS variable` via `style="--myLabel:'activeLabel';"`

```
<div class="red">
    <mat-slide-toggle style="--myLabel:'activeLabel';" label-attr>
    </mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

In `CSS` use the attribute selector to get a reference to your CSS variable and set it to content via `content: var(--myLabel)`.

```
::ng-deep mat-slide-toggle[label-attr] ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle-bar:after {
  content: var(--myLabel);
}
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azgink-dvthvu?file=src/app/slide-toggle-configurable-example.css

Comment: it does not solve the original issue. it adds an element at an incorrect place.

Comment: I see, it adds it after the `label` vs after the `mat-slide-toggle-thumb-container`

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: thank you for looking into my problem, but it didn't work for me. You have used the hardcoded value 'activeLabel', but I want to use the value of variable "activaLabel"