# Display attribute of another element

Tags: css, xml

Let's say I have an XML file:

```
<X attr="1"> something</X>
<Y> something else </Y>
```

How can I do something that would be equivalent to:

```
Y:before
{
   content:attr(1);
}
```

in CSS?

Comment: CSS works the same in XML as it does in HTML, and there's no way for `attr` to get the value of anything other than the selected element (or pseudo-element).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using attribute value of a parent in a child using CSS3 attr function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034739/using-attribute-value-of-a-parent-in-a-child-using-css3-attr-function)

Comment: Using the technique in the linked question, you could possibly use CSS custom properties to do something similar, but I'm not sure it would work without the parent/child relationship. You'd have to play around with ordering of CSS statements.

Comment: @HereticMonkey in my case, there's no parent/child relationship. Guess i'll do without that attribute. Thanks though